# LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc140-mt-1_63.lib'

Tags: c++, boost, dll, visual-studio-2017, lib

I'm working on VS2017, i create a C++ Google Test project. I add the includes directories in C/C++ → General → Additional Include Directories.

Then i added libraries in Properties → Linker → Input and their directories in Properties → Linker → General → Additional Library Directories.

My project compiles fine, but when i build i got 'LNK1104' error for 
'libboost_thread-vc140-mt-1_63.lib'.

Among added libraries, these are all boost lib :

- boost_chrono-vc140-mt-1_63.lib
- boost_date_time-vc140-mt-1_63.lib
- boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_63.lib
- boost_log_setup-vc140-mt-1_63.lib
- boost_log-vc140-mt-1_63.lib
- boost_program_options-vc140-mt-1_63.lib
- boost_regex-vc140-mt-1_63.lib
- boost_system-vc140-mt-1_63.lib
- boost_thread-vc140-mt-1_63.lib

To begin whith is there a difference between the lib name in Linker 'boost_thread-vc140-mt-1_63.lib' and the lib name from the error 'libboost_thread-vc140-mt-1_63.lib'

I checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(LNK1104)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019#cant-open-a-third-party-library-file) for third-party library, all directories and the configuration but i still can't resolve the problem.

Comment: You should link `boost_thread-vc140-mt-1_63.lib` then.

Comment: that's what i did, i added it the input Linker and i specify the path

Comment: *I use the configuration x64 Release

Comment: Maybe `libboost_thread-vc140-mt-1_63.lib` is linked from the code with `#pragma comment`?

Comment: `boost_thread-vc140-mt-1_63.lib` is the dll version, `libboost_thread-vc140-mt-1_63.lib` is the static library. Looks like you've ended up building or downloading the shared library version of boost, either build/download the static version or use the `#defines` in the linked duplicate to tell boost you want to use the shared libraries

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks, i worked whith Preprocessor, i add BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK  and  BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB . And these resolved the Bosst issue. Besides, i still got some LNK2019  errors ; for example LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class testing::internal::String .   I add these #defines  GTEST_HAS_PTHREAD=0 
 and   GTEST_LINKED_AS_SHARED_LIBRARY but it didn't work (it's a GoogleTest project)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix have you linked the gtest libraries? I don't think they link themselves automatically like boost does

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes i linked the directories, i think that the problem comes from creating a GoogleTest project and linking it to a directory that contains gtest.lib and other .lib of my project (i'm working on a complicated project that contains many dependencies) maybe there is a conflict between the gtest.lib that exist and the one from Microsoft.googletest.v140 native

Comment: you don't just need to add the directories, you also need to add the libraries, boost does this for you, gtest doesn't